# How to share configuration files across modules in Maven

Tags: maven, configuration, jar, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

I am working on a java maven project with several modules.

I am facing issues with sharing configuration files from one module to its dependency.
For instance i have a module named *utils* which holds a log.properties file and i would like to use it in another module named *gui*. What is the best practice to do this ?

Currently we put the log.properties in a *config* directory as Maven standard layout suggest it, and it is not included in the jar file. Is it correct ? Should I put it in *resources* instead ?

I use assembly plugin to copy it to a common config directory, this works well, but when I try to build each module individually the config file cannot be reached. How can i solve this ?

Thanks for your help,
Pierre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your configuration in `src/main/resources/config/`. This way it will be included in the jar by default. The maven convention is that only `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` are contained in the final jar by default.

Making property files directly accessible to other modules is not a good practice. You should provide a service in the module owning the configuration that is the only place where those files are accessed. This service will be able to give configurations to other modules. Otherwise you violate the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what i ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure maven to include the `src/main/config` directory in the built artifact by specifying it in the resources section of the pom as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).